# Is $\mathbb{Z}_p \cong \mathbb{Z}[[X]]/(X-p)$?

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, formal-power-series

Let $p$ be a prime number and denote by $\mathbb{Z}_p$ the ring of p-adic integers. Denote by $\mathbb{Z}[[X]]$ the ring of formal power series with integer coefficients and let $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[[X]]}{ (X-p)}$ denote the quotient of $\mathbb{Z}[[X]]$ by the ideal $(X-p)$. Does there exist a ring isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_p \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}[[X]]}{ (X-p)}$ ? If the answer is yes, a constructive proof is preferred.

Comment: What definition do you use for the $p$-adic integers? There are several equivalent definitions, and it will determine what the proof is.

Comment: By the ring of p-adic integers I mean some colimit of the diagram $\mathbb{Z}/ p^{n+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} / p^n$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Since all colimits of this diagram are canonically isomorphic, the answer to my question should be independent of the choice. In fact, my question can be restated in the following way. Do there exist ring homomorphisms $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[[X]]}{(X-p)} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p^n$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$ which make $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[[X]]}{(X-p)}$ into a colimit? In any case, I leave the choice of a particular construction of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ to the one answering.

Comment: 2 close votes, again for a normal question. This really p***es me off in the last weeks on MSE. @greenbean Just ignore them!

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg No work shown, pretty standard close vote. Also clearly phrased like a homework problem (the last line is the big hint there.)

Comment: Put your work and definition in the question. A person should not need to read the comments to get the complete question. @greenbean

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, there is an isomorphism of topological rings $\mathbb{Z}[[X]]/\langle X - p\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_p$.

**Hint.** Construct a continuous surjective homomorphism $\varphi : \mathbb{Z}[[X]] \to \mathbb{Z}_p$ with $\ker(\varphi)=\langle X - p \rangle$.

The information $\varphi(X-p)=0$ already tells you what $\varphi(X)$ must be, and then extend the definition to all of $\mathbb{Z}[[X]]$.

Comment: The map $\varphi$ is easy to construct, but it takes some work to show its kernel is generated by $X-p$.

Comment: A tempting cleaner-looking way would be to observe that $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^n,X-p)\cong \mathbb{Z}/(p^n)$ and take the inverse limit.  I don't see a way to make that work purely formally, though, since it's not obvious that $\mathbb{Z}[[X]]/(X-p)$ should actually be the inverse limit of $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^n,X-p)$.

Comment: Yes, we interchange limits with colimits - always an interesting adventure!

Comment: I didn't want to flesh out the proof for the kernel since the OP didn't really show much of own effort so far (as already Thomas pointed out, maybe it is just a homework exercise).

Comment: I would prove it by showing that modulo $X-p$ every formal power series is $\equiv \sum_{n \geq 0} a_n X^n$ with $0 \leq a_n < p$, and then use uniqueness of power series expansions in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. But there are other ways, too.